# Securly call an API through reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, postman

I am working on a **React.js** web app.In it I want to register a user on my app.currently I am sending username and password to  `'/register'` route of my **nodejs** server by **axios** post to register the user.But here's the problem: if anyone sends the username and password to the `'/register'` route through 'postman app' he is also able to register.how can I prevent this?

Comment: This is the normal HTTP behavior. Your `API server` (Node) usually shouldn't care about which client is used (Web, Mobile app, curl).  Can you explain why is this a problem in your case?

Comment: Because if anyone can  use that route then he can register fake users that are not actually using the app basically he can do spamming

Comment: Basically my question is how can I use a private API in front end frameworks like react because I can't use API key there because it is not secure to use API key in front end.